# Pytorch Cuda for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, python-3.7

I'm trying to get pytorch with cuda 10 compatibility via :
conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
from(https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-with-cuda-11-compatibility/89254)
but there is timeout error:

```
    Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
pytorch-mutex-1.0    | 3 KB      |                                                                                                                          |   0%
torchvision-0.12.0   | 8.8 MB    |                                                                                                                          |   0%
ffmpeg-4.3           | 9.9 MB    |                                                                                                                          |   0%
pytorch-1.11.0       | 622.9 MB  |                                                                                                                          |   0%

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch/pytorch-mutex-1.0-cuda.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch/pytorch-mutex-1.0-cuda.tar.bz2>
    Elapsed: -
```

Comment: thats your connection or connectivity issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was running WSL2 and didn't  shut down for many days. A reboot fixed the issue.